# Cambiar lenguaje del DatetimePicker en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datetimepicker

estoy usando un DateTimePicker para Bootstrap y no me deja cambiar el idioma del mismo a pesar de que la documentación dice que sí se puede, me marca el error que es una **opción no reconocida.**
Estoy usando la versión 4.17.47 del DateTimePicker y la versión 2.9.0 de Moment.js

Les presento el código:

Este sería lo que hay en el head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Parte del form donde selecciono la fecha:

```
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="na_fvigencia" class="col-form-label">Fecha de vigencia</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="id_0">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="na_fvigencia" name="na_fvigencia"  required>
                            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                                 <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="na_fvisible" class="col-form-label">Fecha de visibilidad</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="id_1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="na_fvisible" name="na_fvisible"  required>
                            <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                                 <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Por último el script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#id_0').datetimepicker({
            "allowInputToggle": true,
            "showClose": true,
            "showClear": true,
            "showTodayButton": true,
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A",
        });
    $('#id_1').datetimepicker({
            "allowInputToggle": true,
            "showClose": true,
            "showClear": true,
            "showTodayButton": true,
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A",
        });
});</script>
```

Cabe mencionar que ya he utilizado las opciones de locale y language dentro de la función que ejecuta el datetimepicker. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Por favor muéstranos cómo estás usando las opciones de locale y language dentro de la función

Comment: @JheymanMejia los usé de está forma amigo:

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#id_0').datetimepicker({
            "allowInputToggle": true,
            "showClose": true,
            "showClear": true,
            "showTodayButton": true,
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A",
            "language": "es",
            "locale": "es-MX"
        });

Comment: Agrega bajo tu moment.js la librería del idioma correspondiente: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/locale/es-mx.js"></script>` Acabo de hacer una prueba y funciona. SIno, por favor, haz clic en [edit] y crea un [example]